# React - useEffect with async setState causing additional re-renders

Tags: reactjs, promise, react-hooks

I have a React hook here

```
export const useConfigDetails = (resourceName: string) => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = React.useState<boolean>(true);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState<AxiosError>(undefined);
  const [allEnvDetails, setAllEnvDetails] = React.useState<ResourceDetails[]>();


  React.useEffect(() => {
   const configPromises = ['dev', 'stage', 'prod'].map((environment: Environment) =>
    axios.get('someUrlGetEndpoint'));

    Promise.all(configPromises)
      .then((resp: ResourceDetails[]) => setAllEnvDetails(resp))
      .catch((err: AxiosError) => setError(err))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, [resourceName]);

  return { allEnvDetails, isLoading };
};
```

What I am trying to achieve - Whenever the `resourceName` changes, it will need to refresh and make calls to all different environments (`dev, stage and prod`), and return the latest `allEnvDetails` back. It should avoid other re-renders

Ideally, there should only be 3 `axios.get` calls that correspond to the 3 environments. However, it's being called 9 times (3 times for each environment).

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58697073/multiple-times-render-in-react-functional-component-with-hooks), I am using the setState within a promise resolve/reject block, so whenever state within the functional component (my hook) is updated it will trigger another, unwanted re-render.

Is there a better way to refactor/resolve this issue? I had been searching for a while, but I'm not sure what can be improved.

Comment: you have three  state for initial ( 3 renders) which will double the re-renders due to `React.strictMode` and 3 more after component did mount so it becomes 9, here to answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62258852/react-component-render-twice-using-usestate

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add condition if(isLoading) in begining of function:

```
`
React.useEffect(() => {
if(isLoading){
const configPromises = ['dev', 'stage', 'prod'].map((environment: 
Environment) =>
axios.get('someUrlGetEndpoint'));

Promise.all(configPromises)
  .then((resp: ResourceDetails[]) => setAllEnvDetails(resp))
  .catch((err: AxiosError) => setError(err))
  .finally(() => setLoading(false));
}
}, [resourceName]);
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
export const useConfigDetails = (resourceName: string) => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = React.useState<boolean>(true);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState<AxiosError>(undefined);
  const [allEnvDetails, setAllEnvDetails] = React.useState<ResourceDetails[]>();


  React.useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
          try{
              setLoading(true)

              const dev = await axios.get('someUrlGetEndpoint');
              const stage = await axios.get('someUrlGetEndpoint');
              const prod = await axios.get('someUrlGetEndpoint');

              setAllEnvDetails([
                  dev,
                  stage,
                  prod
              ])

              setLoading(false)
          }catch(e) {
              setError(e);
              setLoading(false)
          }
      })()
  }, [resourceName]);

  return { allEnvDetails, isLoading };
};
```